# How to adjust height's of ImageView in RelativeLayout in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale, android-relativelayout

I've created an view to display errors that contains:

- an **image**
- a description **text**
- a "Retry" **button**

The description **text** must be fully displayed: it is displayed on 3 lines. The "Retry" **button** has a fixed height and must be visible too. The **image** must be resized according to the available space.

***For now, the text is not fully displayed: only 2 lines are visible. It seems that the image's size is not enough reduced...***

This view is based on a `RelativeLayout`, and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/color_white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ErrorImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cards_error_image_margin_top"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ErrorTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/ErrorImageView"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/cards_error_text_margin_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cards_error_text_margin_top"
        style="@style/CustomFont30Marine"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RetryButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/cards_error_retry_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cards_error_retry_button_margin_bottom"
        style="@style/WhiteCustomButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***Is there a way to achieve this through the designer? Or do I need to resize the image programmatically?***

The expected result looks like this:

[image: Expected result]

The actual result looks like this:

[image: Actual result]

Comment: Add some screenshots of what you need and what you're currently getting

Comment: Hi @Sdghasemi, I've added some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to replicate the design as per your requirements .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ErrorImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/ErrorTextView"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ErrorTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:lines="3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_above="@id/RetryButton"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/RetryButton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Kaveri, thanks for your suggestion, but this doesn't work. I get this error: "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/RetryButton'). (APT0000)".

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ErrorImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cards_error_image_margin_top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ErrorTextView"
        style="@style/CustomFont30Marine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cards_error_text_margin_top"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RetryButton"
        style="@style/WhiteCustomButton"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/cards_error_retry_button_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cards_error_retry_button_margin_bottom" />

</LinearLayout>
```